# Sporadic Redis TimeoutError from Heroku Rails app

Tags: ruby-on-rails, heroku, azure, timeout, redis

We're running a rails app via heroku that connects to a windows azure VM, where I've set up a redis master/slave to act as a cache (slash quick reference data store).  The problem is, we sporadically get redis timeouts.  This is with a timeout of 10 seconds (which I know is more than it needs), and reestablishing redis connections on fork.  And using hiredis as a driver.

Anyone have a clue why this might be happening?  I know heroku and the azure vm are hosted on different coasts, so there's a bit of latency; could there be TCP request drops?  I'm fairly out of ideas.

Comment: We are having the exact issue in 2018. Do you remember how you solved it back then?